# ASP . NET Label not update with jquery ajax/ POST

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms, updatepanel

I try to update labels by using script. After the script, every Label.value already have data, but it's not update at page. Here is my code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "a", @" <script type='text/javascript'> 
        function bbfb() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ImgService.asmx/GetAllImgs',
                data: '{}',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    var cars = msg.d;
                     var TextBoxError = document.getElementById('Labelxyz123');
                     var TextBoxError1 = document.getElementById('LabelLogContent');
                     TextBoxError.value = cars;
                      TextBoxError1.value = cars;
                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    alert('fail');
                }
            });
        }

        function BindEvents() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                bbfb();

            //At this point, all of the labels already have data
            var TextBoxError = document.getElementById('Labelxyz123');
            var TextBoxError1 = document.getElementById('LabelLogContent');
            alert(TextBoxError.value);
            alert(TextBoxError1.value);
            //

            }, 0);
        }
        BindEvents();

</script>", false);
            UpdatePanelEdit_on.Update();
```

And here is my asp code:

```
<asp:Label ID="Labelxyz123" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="a"></asp:Label>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelEdit_on" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"
        ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelLogContent" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="a"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Both Label inside and outside update panel were not update.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my problem. The way to fix this is change async into true

```
 async:true
```

change

```
var TextBoxError = document.getElementById('LabelLogContent');
TextBoxError.value = cars;
```

into

```
$('#LabelLogContent).Text = cars
```

The problem is label not update from client side.